# Trying to connect sql linked server from vba and vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, vba, linked-server

I have successfully connected (Using linked server ) oracle 10 g server into sql server 2008 ..

Now how do I connect though vb.net and vba ..

I have tried though system DSN but I can see only the databases which listed under Databases(refer image) not linked servers.

[image]

Is there any way to connect the linked server from Vba and vb.net or any suggestions.

Thanks for your help in advance(Please help me I'm new to this :=( )

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this in the code yet?

```
 Dim SQLConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection  
 SQLConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=servername;" & _
 "Initial Catalog=databasename;" & _
 "User ID=username;" & _  
 "Password=userpassword;"
```

Comment: Yes tried it throws error ..run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)';

Comment: You could try to disable the primary key and see if you can at least get your connection.